Why is this QAbstractItemModel based model not working?
I create a simple QMainWindow app as follows:
The header file:
//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H


#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QVBoxLayout>


#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}



class MyTreeModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
public:
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyTreeModel(QObject *parent=NULL);

    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column,const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;


    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

};


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    


    QTreeView * view;
    MyTreeModel *model;


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QVBoxLayout * layout;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

The source file:
//mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>




QModelIndex MyTreeModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return QModelIndex();
}

QVariant MyTreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    return "111";
}

QVariant MyTreeModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                               int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        if(section==0)
            return "Column0";
        else if(section==1)
            return "Column1";
        else if(section==2)
            return "Column2";
        else
            return QVariant();
    }
    else
        return QVariant();
}

QModelIndex MyTreeModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
            const
{

    return createIndex(row, column, NULL);

}

int MyTreeModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 3;
}

int MyTreeModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 2;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    model=new MyTreeModel();
    view= new QTreeView(this);
    view->setModel(model);

    layout= new QVBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(view);
    QWidget *window = new QWidget();
    window->setLayout(layout);
    setCentralWidget(window);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

I expect it will show a 2 rows * 3 columns of "111", but it does not. It only shows the header. If I change  QVariant MyTreeModel::headerData to:
QVariant MyTreeModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                               int role) const
{

        if(section==0)
            return "Column0";
        else if(section==1)
            return "Column1";
        else if(section==2)
            return "Column2";
        else
            return QVariant();

}

It will show nothing. The header also disappears.
Why?

Does QAbstractItemModelTester provide any useful diagnostics?

@G.M. I'm using Qt 4 which does not have this class.

@William Qt4 has been deprecated for at least 10 years. Even if the Qt model/view programming implementation hasn't changed that much in the meantime, the fact that you're using such an old library should be highlighted in your post (and in its tags), otherwise we'd (properly) assume that you're using the currently supported versions, which may behave differently.

Your code a has a couple of issues.  Firstly, because it's a single level model the index, rowCount and columnCount members should only return 'real' values when the specified parent index is invalid (i.e. the nominal root index).  So those members become...
QModelIndex MyTreeModel::index (int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
  if (parent.isValid())
    return {};
  return createIndex(row, column, nullptr);
}

int MyTreeModel::columnCount (const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
  if (parent.isValid())
    return 0;
  return 3;
}

int MyTreeModel::rowCount (const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
  if (parent.isValid())
    return 0;
  return 2;
}

Secondly, your MyTreeModel::data member always returns (effectively) QString("111").  That will fail for those roles where a QString can't be converted to the expected type: e.g. QSize for Qt::SizeHintRole.  So the data member becomes...
QVariant MyTreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
  if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
    return {};
  return "111";
}

With the above changes the code appears to work as expected.

It should also be noted that, while it may make sense for the simplicity of the test case (which fundamentally creates a 2d table model), using null as pointer for createIndex() is wrong in principle, when creating a what could be a tree model.

@G.M.  Your modified code does work! Thanks. In fact, when I just modify the data function as yours, it can show the 2 rows*3 columns of "111". But the program crashes when I click the arrow on the tree view to expand a row. Don't know why? I'm curious about the roles and timing of index, data, rowCount, columnCount, parent in the model. How do they work together to show the actual data on the view?

@musicamante If not using null pointer in createIndex(), what should I use for a tree model?

@William you shouldn't normally care too much about the "timing" of index(), data(), rowCount() and columnCount(): they may be called in very different moments depending on various needs. The reason for which you must implement everything G.M. says is not because of the order in which functions may be called, but because of their implementation must be done appropriately: the parent argument of rowCount() and columnCount() is used to return the number of possible child items for the given parent, and since you're always arbitrarily returning a value >= 0, this means that »

@William » every item fundamentally has other children (in your example, 6, 3 rows and 2 columns). This is wrong, because it causes infinite recursion, as every one of those children will, in turn, have other children. I strongly suggest you to patiently study the Model/View programming guide, and do some proper learning tests starting with mono dimensional models ("lists"), then bi dimensional ("tables") and finally tree models, all with the related views: QListView, QTableView, QTreeView respectively. The third argument of »

@William » createIndex() is normally not required for simple models (1D and 2D) since their logical coordinates in the models are obvious, but tree models do require a reference for the given row and column, otherwise the model will have no way to know if item at row X and column Y is referred to the top level, or a child, a grand child, etc. There's some clarification about this aspect in the doc above (and in the QAbstractItemModel docs), but you should really start by properly understanding simpler models before moving into tree ones; those are steps you can not skip.
